# Solving a system of 11 non-linear equations in 11 unknowns

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a system of 11 equations in 11  unknowns that are here defined as 11 particular elements of a $4\times4$ matrix M. The rest 5 of the matrix elements are fed with random values between -100 to 100. The code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
(*Initialization*)
x1 = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x2 = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x3 = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x0 = RandomInteger[Floor[Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]]]; 
M = Array[x, {4, 4}]; 
x[1, 2] = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x[1, 3] = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x[1, 4] = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x[2, 1] = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]; 
x[3, 1] = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}];
(*Equations definition*) 
eq1 = x[1, 1]*x0 + x[1, 2]*x1 + x[1, 3]*x2 + x[1, 4]*x3 == 0; 
eq2 = x[1, 2]*x[1, 3] - x[2, 2]*x[2, 3] - x[3, 2]*x[3, 3] - x[4, 2]*x[4, 3] == 0; 
eq3 = x[1, 2]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 2]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 2]*x[3, 4] - x[4, 2]*x[4, 4] == 0; 
eq4 = x[1, 3]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 3]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 3]*x[3, 4] - x[4, 3]*x[4, 4] == 0; 
eq5 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 2] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 2] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 2] - x[4, 1]*x[4, 2] == 0; 
eq6 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 3] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 3] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 3] - x[4, 1]*x[4, 3] == 0; 
eq7 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 4] - x[4, 1]*x[4, 4] == 0; 
eq8 = x[1, 1]^2 - x[2, 1]^2 - x[3, 1]^2 - x[4, 1]^2 == 1; eq9 = x[1, 2]^2 - x[2, 2]^2 - x[3, 2]^2 - x[4, 2]^2 == -1; 
eq10 = x[1, 3]^2 - x[2, 3]^2 - x[3, 3]^2 - x[4, 3]^2 == -1; 
eq11 = x[1, 4]^2 - x[2, 4]^2 - x[3, 4]^2 - x[4, 4]^2 == -1; 
(* Solving the system*)
FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11}, {{x[1, 1], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[2, 2], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[2, 3], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, 
    {x[2, 4], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[3, 2], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[3, 3], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[3, 4], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, 
    {x[4, 1], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[4, 2], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[4, 3], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}, {x[4, 4], RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}]}}, Method -> "Newton"]; 
  MatrixForm[M]
```

The code on execution flags the following error:

> FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point
>   {x[1,1],x[2,2],x[2,3],x[2,4],x[3,2],x[3,3],x[3,4],x[4,1],x[4,2],x[4,3],x[4,4]}
>   = {-4915.,4024.,8670.,-8350.,-6813.,9054.,3639.,3690.,7819.,5139.,-1058.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

I understand the way it tries to solve this using a set of 11 initial values that don't produce a singular Jacobian of the derivative matrix. Can anyone suggest a way to find a good set of initial values or to resort to some other method?

**Edit:**

I went through my code again. I had 11 equations and 16 unknown variables. So I had to fix 5 matrix element values by hand. It turns out, different choices for this set of 5 elements leads to different behavior for the solution of the system. I tweaked the choice and now the GroebnerBasis function doesn't return {1}, like earlier. So there exists a solution. I expanded my code a bit to show how well the solution obtained using FindRoot satisfies my constraints(which it doesn't so well!). The issue of convergence has to be addressed here. Mathematica screams of failure of convergence every time I run the code.

The new updated code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(*Initialization*)
x1 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]
x2 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]
x3 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]
x0 = RandomInteger[Floor[Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]]]
M = Array[x, {4, 4}];
x[1, 1] = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}];
x[2, 2] = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}];
x[3, 3] = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}];
x[4, 4] = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}];
x[1, 2] = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}];
(*Equations definition*)
eq1 = x[1, 1]*x0 + x[1, 2]*x1 + x[1, 3]*x2 + x[1, 4]*x3 == 0;
eq2 = x[1, 2]*x[1, 3] - x[2, 2]*x[2, 3] - x[3, 2]*x[3, 3] - 
    x[4, 2]*x[4, 3] == 0;
eq3 = x[1, 2]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 2]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 2]*x[3, 4] - 
    x[4, 2]*x[4, 4] == 0;
eq4 = x[1, 3]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 3]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 3]*x[3, 4] - 
    x[4, 3]*x[4, 4] == 0;
eq5 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 2] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 2] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 2] - 
    x[4, 1]*x[4, 2] == 0;
eq6 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 3] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 3] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 3] - 
    x[4, 1]*x[4, 3] == 0;
eq7 = x[1, 1]*x[1, 4] - x[2, 1]*x[2, 4] - x[3, 1]*x[3, 4] - 
    x[4, 1]*x[4, 4] == 0;
eq8 = x[1, 1]^2 - x[2, 1]^2 - x[3, 1]^2 - x[4, 1]^2 - 1 == 0;
eq9 = x[1, 2]^2 - x[2, 2]^2 - x[3, 2]^2 - x[4, 2]^2 + 1 == 0;
eq10 = x[1, 3]^2 - x[2, 3]^2 - x[3, 3]^2 - x[4, 3]^2 + 1 == 0;
eq11 = x[1, 4]^2 - x[2, 4]^2 - x[3, 4]^2 - x[4, 4]^2 + 1 == 0;
(*Checking existence of a solution*)
eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, 
  eq11}; polys = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]; vars = 
 Variables[polys]; Not[GroebnerBasis[polys, vars] == {1}]
(*Solving the system*)
min = 0; max = 5;
sol = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, 
    eq11}, {{x[1, 3], RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[1, 4], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[2, 1], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[2, 3], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[2, 4], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[3, 1], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[3, 2], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[3, 4], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[4, 1], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[4, 2], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}, {x[4, 3], 
     RandomInteger[{min, max}]}}, Method -> "Newton", 
   MaxIterations -> 1*^1000];
M = M /. sol;
M // MatrixForm
(* Checking how good is the solution*)
eq1 = M[[1, 1]]*x0 + M[[1, 2]]*x1 + M[[1, 3]]*x2 + M[[1, 4]]*x3
eq2 = M[[1, 2]]*M[[1, 3]] - M[[2, 2]]*M[[2, 3]] - 
  M[[3, 2]]*M[[3, 3]] - M[[4, 2]]*M[[4, 3]]
eq3 = M[[1, 2]]*M[[1, 4]] - M[[2, 2]]*M[[2, 4]] - 
  M[[3, 2]]*M[[3, 4]] - M[[4, 2]]*M[[4, 4]]
eq4 = M[[1, 3]]*M[[1, 4]] - M[[2, 3]]*M[[2, 4]] - 
  M[[3, 3]]*M[[3, 4]] - M[[4, 3]]*M[[4, 4]]
eq5 = M[[1, 1]]*M[[1, 2]] - M[[2, 1]]*M[[2, 2]] - 
  M[[3, 1]]*M[[3, 2]] - M[[4, 1]]*M[[4, 2]]
eq6 = M[[1, 1]]*M[[1, 3]] - M[[2, 1]]*M[[2, 3]] - 
  M[[3, 1]]*M[[3, 3]] - M[[4, 1]]*M[[4, 3]]
eq7 = M[[1, 1]]*M[[1, 4]] - M[[2, 1]]*M[[2, 4]] - 
  M[[3, 1]]*M[[3, 4]] - M[[4, 1]]*M[[4, 4]]
eq8 = M[[1, 1]]^2 - M[[2, 1]]^2 - M[[3, 1]]^2 - M[[4, 1]]^2 - 1
eq9 = M[[1, 2]]^2 - M[[2, 2]]^2 - M[[3, 2]]^2 - M[[4, 2]]^2 + 1
eq10 = M[[1, 3]]^2 - M[[2, 3]]^2 - M[[3, 3]]^2 - M[[4, 3]]^2 + 1
eq11 = M[[1, 4]]^2 - M[[2, 4]]^2 - M[[3, 4]]^2 - M[[4, 4]]^2 + 1
```

Comment: Some context on where these equations came from would be nice.

Comment: This is related to a finding a Lorentz transformation matrix for moving to a frame where two spacelike separated events become simultaneous in the new frame.

Comment: @J.M. Any suggestions?

Comment: The equations are apparently inconsistent. `In[195]:= 
eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11};
polys = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];
vars = Variables[polys];
GroebnerBasis[polys, vars]

Out[198]= {1}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This might be a problem. Thanks for pointing it out. I will recheck this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have sorted out the earlier issue. Still there is convergence problem. What to do hereafter?

Comment: The issue now is that all solutions are complex-valued, so `FindRoot` will have trouble if given real values for initial points (guesses). You can get all the solutions by `solns = NSolve[polys, vars]` to see this.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks